# django object saving differs in sqlite in development and mysql in production

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

In  my view I am saving or say updating object like this :

```
Notification.objects.filter(id=self.npk, body=q, viewed=False).update(viewed=True)
```

Its working in the development. Its turning the notifications to viewed but in production its not.

In development I have used sqlite3 and in production I used mysql..

Whats the problem ??

Comment: What do you mean by query log says.. it says nothing just dont update it..

Comment: Are you sure the query returns any objects at all, given the three filtering params you have specified?

Comment: Since a model's `id` field is generally a unique value, I don't think you need the other selections. What happens if you just tried `Notification.objects.filter(id=self.npk).update(viewed=True)` ?

Comment: somewhere I am decreasing the notification count if this part is updated. When I check from admin its not updated I mean notification is not updated to viewed=True

Comment: do that cause a problem like filtering with many field ??

Answer (score 0):

I think that mysql is creating problem because it saves the True,False as varchar not as boolean. 
You can alternatively use viewed = 0 for False and 1 for true, by making viewed as int type in both mysql and django model